# nservicebus unobtrusive mode not picking up handlers or processing messages

Tags: nservicebus

I am trying to put together a prototype using Nservicebus using the unobtrusive mode by defining custom conventions. I started trying to run my endpoint in the NServicebus host but had no luck with it picking up a message that I publish. I took the Unobtrusive sample application available from Nservicebus and replaced its contents with my messages and handlers. It appears to detect the messages based on convention (I see it in the console output when the app is running), but does not appear to register for those messages based on the handlers I have in the Server application. I don't see the message being put in the queue and I cannot see an active or inactive endpoint in service pulse either when the application is running.

I have tried many different "fixes" and have scoured the internet, stack overflow, and the Nservicebus documentation and have not found any information to point me in the right direction.

Here is my server endpoint config:

```
    BusConfiguration busConfiguration = new BusConfiguration();

busConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
busConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
busConfiguration.UseDataBus<FileShareDataBus>()
    .BasePath(@"..\..\..\DataBusShare\");
busConfiguration.RijndaelEncryptionService();

busConfiguration.ApplyCustomConventions();

using (IBus bus = Bus.Create(busConfiguration).Start())
{
  Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
  Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void ApplyCustomConventions(this BusConfiguration busConfiguration)  
{

ConventionsBuilder conventions = busConfiguration.Conventions();
conventions.DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Commands"));
conventions.DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Events"));
conventions.DefiningMessagesAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace == "Messages");
conventions.DefiningEncryptedPropertiesAs(p => p.Name.StartsWith("Encrypted"));
//conventions.DefiningDataBusPropertiesAs(p => p.Name.EndsWith("DataBus"));
conventions.DefiningExpressMessagesAs(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Express"));
conventions
  .DefiningTimeToBeReceivedAs(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Expires")
      ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
      : TimeSpan.MaxValue
  );
}
```

The ApplyCustomConventions method is shared between my message publisher and the Server endpoint.

Here is my Server endpoint .exe app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="RijndaelEncryptionServiceConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.RijndaelEncryptionServiceConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
  </configSections>
  <RijndaelEncryptionServiceConfig Key="gdDbqRpqdRbTs3mhdZh8qCaDaxJXl+e7"/>
</configuration>
```

There is no error on publish and the message is never received.

**Update**: I have narrowed this down to it not working when i try to publish events and the endpoint will not subscribe unless I do an endpoint mapping. Furthermore, even after I publish an event with the endpoint mapping in place it is still not picked up by my endpoint handlers.

I have a questions here. In the unobtrusive example from Particular it does not set up any endpoint mappings to be able to send commands and messages, it sets up a endpoint based on the assembly name. Does this not work with events and publish? I took the unobtrusive example and put one event message in Messages.dll, and added one handler for that event in the Server.exe, and changed the Client.exe to be able to publish that event and it does not work.
I will try to post my code somewhere when i get a chance. Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you share your code on Dropbox or github?

I assume you saw this? http://docs.particular.net/samples/unobtrusive/#Nuget-v5_x

Comment: For ServicePulse to see the endpoint's heartbeat you need to add the heartbeat plugin: http://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/plugins/heartbeat

Comment: I have service pulse setup and the proper Nugets included.

Comment: Hi Chris, if you didn't sort this out, send me an email to support at particular.net and i'll try and help

Answer (score 1):

When running an endpoint with unobtrusive mode, make sure you are doing the definitions in both the sender and receiver.

Also, post some of your endpoint configuration code here, that might help troubleshooting.

Do you get any errors when doing the send at the receiving endpoint? Much of the time some type of error is thrown that can help troubleshoot this.

Comment: In relation to your edit. Each assembly that is created has it's own set of queues behind the scenes that is used for transporting message, and within .Net each different project is created within its' own assembly. If you publisher and subscriber are within the same assembly (same project) then I don't think you have to do a mapping, but I might be incorrect on that assumption.

Also, if this helped you out, please make this as the "answer" or up vote me. I'm trying to build my StackOverflow points. :)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in your app.config you do not have the endpoint mappings defined. This is needed on both the "frontend" and "backend" projects to route the messages to right spot. Here is a snippet of what mine is for an application called "myapplication":

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="myapplication.Commands" Endpoint="myapplication.Backend" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

More information about this can be found here: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/specify-message-destination

Answer (score 0):

Both endpoints will require the unobtrusive mappings. The subscriber endpoint should be configured to subscribe to the messages. See here for how to configure the subscriber:

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/publish-subscribe/configuration

The App.config will looks something like this for your subscriber:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
  </configSections>
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Assembly="Shared" Endpoint="Samples.PubSub.MyPublisher"/>
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
</configuration>
```